# How to get multiple instances of quip.apps.auth?

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm trying to create a quip live app that can login to multiple instances of Salesforce orgs. It would be great if there is a way by which I can get a new instance of quip.apps.auth for each live app instance that I put in the Quip document.

Right now all the instances of my live app in a certain document share the same instance of quip.apps.auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one auth instance per configured auth in your dev console, but you can have as many configured auths as you like. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there's a way to dynamically add new auth instances at this time.

Comment: But the Salesforce record live app seems to do that perfectly, somehow. It's able to connect to multiple orgs, and allows to maintain multiple instances of a live app in a document each connected to a different org.

Comment: That's true - the Salesforce apps use a private authentication mechanism that is not yet available to developers. We'll improve this area in the future but right now there isn't a way to use this functionality directly.